# VS 2015 This application could not be started on win10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

When I try to run application in VS 2015 on Win 10 (app is for win 8.1) i get "This application could not be started" error. First I thought it is problem with my project and I have tried "all" propositions i could have found. Then I have started new simple project and that would not work either. Everything have been working until update to win 10. Unfortunately win 10 is a necessity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to my problem. For some unknown reason the project(solution) need to be on disk c:. If it were on other disk (in my case d:) the problem occurred. It is stupid but nonetheless it works.